# "@2x" images are enough for iOS 9 devices?

Tags: ios, ios9, retina-display

"@2x" images are enough if only iOS9 devices so at least iPhone 5 devices are supported?

Comment: @sasquatch https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3kuy1o/is_the_ipad_pro_a_3x_device_what_is_the_size_of/

Comment: @János why did you mark my answer as unsolved by the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether **@2x** images are enough depends on two factors:

1. Are you supporting iPads? If this is the case, then you will need **@1x** images as well for the iPad 2 and iPad Mini 1
2. Are you supporting the *Plus* variants of the iPhone 6, 6s and 7? If so, you will also need **@3x** images.

**EDIT**: If your app only supports iOS 10, it should be good enough to simply have **@2x** and **@3x** images, as the two iPads mentioned above do not support this version.